# Segmentation Fault before main - wrong Eclipse config?

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing

I wrote a library with some unit tests. Everything was fine when I was testing it through a tester which used to execute the unit test by linking this library.

Bad design, I know.

That's why I decided to create a new Build Config in eclipse and I added a main in the unit test folder:

```
//#include "Tester.h"
//#include "Logger.h"


int main()
{
    //test::Tester testRunner;

    //testRunner.run();

    return 0;
}
```

This is doing Segmentation Fault. I tried to debug and to add printf and I'm sure that the main is not called at all.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fffffffdfe8 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) quit
```

I don't use eclipse to run this, I only use eclipse to build it. Maybe some of my libraries are missing and it crashes? Normally if I have an empty main it shouldn't care about missing libraries, right?

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Static initialization fiasco? What libraries do you link against? Are they all compiled with debug symbols? Are you sure the issue is before and not after main?

Comment: @JohanLundberg Totally sure that is before, I debugged and added a fprintf on stderr at beginning of main. I will check the rest of your comments, thanks.

Comment: We don't know what's in the headers or in other source files. Try an empty project, a single source file with only an empty `main`, and no headers.

Comment: @n.m. well... it's already empty.

Comment: Are you sure there are no external libs or other source files? Can you find logs of the compiler invocation? Are you building the debug configurationn